# How to find the percentage value from file using batch file

Tags: batch-file

html file with content

Coverage by assemblyPOroject A90%

generated using Partcover

Please help me find the percentage value i.e 90% using the batch file

Comment: Why don't you try something first and then post the code here if you cant get it to work? Hint: use the [find command](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/find.php)

Comment: @Fredrik, the find command can find the % sign, that's all. ITs not able to get the value...

Comment: I am very new to batch scripting. I tried to find the percentage value with findstr /R command with regular expressions but no success. 
If it is static value i could used find command, but with partcover report generation value is dynamic. Please let me know any regular expression to be used .

Answer (score 0):

```
>find "%" name.txt

---------- NAME.TXT
Coverage by assemblyPOroject A90%

>set string=Coverage by assemblyPOroject A90%

>echo %string%
Coverage by assemblyPOroject A90%

>echo %string:~30,2%
90
```

If you find that the batch language isn't powerful enough to do what you want - and it likely won't take you too long to get to that point - you can use the [Windows PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419). This isn't installed by default on all versions of Windows, but you can download it free of charge.

If you don't like the PowerShell language, there's Python/Perl...

Comment: Glad I could help; don't forget to upvote and accept if you liked it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vbscript` (not tested)

```
Set objFS=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFile = "c:\test\file"
Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfLine
    strLine= objFile.ReadLine
    s = Split(strLine," ")    'save each word into array
    ' display 
    For i=0 To Ubound(s)
        If InStr(s(i),"%") > 0 Then
        WScript.Echo s(i)
    End If 
    Next
Loop
```

For more information on how to use vbscript, [download the manual](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=2764) and go through it